# Use R apriori for numeric/continuous attributes

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining, apriori

I am trying to use Apriori in R for numeric attributes. I discretized the attributes

```
mat1 = discretize(table[1:699,1:1])
mat1 = cbind(mat1, discretize(table[1:699,2:2]))
rules <- apriori(mat1, parameter = list(supp = 0.5, conf = 0.9, target = "rules"))
```

But apriori treats all non-zero values as 1.

```
Apriori

Parameter specification:
 confidence minval smax arem  aval originalSupport support minlen maxlen target   ext
        0.9    0.1    1 none FALSE            TRUE     0.5      1     10  rules FALSE

Algorithmic control:
 filter tree heap memopt load sort verbose
    0.1 TRUE TRUE  FALSE TRUE    2    TRUE

Absolute minimum support count: 349 

set item appearances ...[0 item(s)] done [0.00s].
set transactions ...[2 item(s), 699 transaction(s)] done [0.00s].
sorting and recoding items ... [2 item(s)] done [0.00s].
creating transaction tree ... done [0.00s].
checking subsets of size 1 2 done [0.00s].
writing ... [4 rule(s)] done [0.00s].
creating S4 object  ... done [0.00s].
Warning message:
In asMethod(object) :
  matrix contains values other than 0 and 1! Setting all entries != 0 to 1.
```

As apriori takes input as binary valued, how to apply association rule mining on continuous-numeric valued attributes?

Comment: Can you explain how an association rule in the continuous case looks like?

Comment: Something like 1, 2, 3, 7 => 9   According to this rule, if the 1, 2, 3, 7 input parameters have the same value, 9th
input parameter should also have the same value. Therefore, we can say that the ninth
input value depends on the other inputs

Comment: What does `mat1` look like?

Comment: mat1 has numeric values 1,2,3 etc

Comment: Then you probably still need to convert it to binary data!

Answer (score 0):

I would not use `discretize()`, I would apply the apriori()-function to a dataframe including your data as factors, which you could define like this:

```
mat1 <- data.frame(
  X1 = as.character(table[1:699,1:1])
  ,X2 = as.character(table[1:699,2:2])
  ,stringsAsFactors = TRUE); #also by default
```